# How to Use DateTime Web Form Field to Pass DateTime Parameter into Database using Stored Procedure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, webforms, parameter-passing

I am trying to use a datetime field in a webform to pass a datetime parameter into a database.

The datetime format in the database is:

```
2015-05-18 00:00:00.000
```

The webform input field is:

```
<asp:TextBox ClientIDMode="Static" ID="txtEffDate" runat="server" CssClass="calendarImg" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:ImageButton runat="Server" ID="ImageButton1" ImageUrl="~/images/cal.gif" BorderStyle="None"
AlternateText="Click to show calendar" TabIndex="300" Style="cursor: pointer;" Width="16px" />
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtEffDate" PopupButtonID="ImageButton1" />
```

The specific parameter code behind is:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@desiredEffDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = txtEffDate;
```

The specific parameter in the stored procedure is:

```
@desiredEffDate datetime,
```

How should I define the datetime correctly or convert it to the proper format in the code behind?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Any reason you're using a textbox rather than a date/time control of some description? How do you want users to enter the values?

Comment: I am using a calendar extender, but the field is also open for manual entry. I accidentally did not include the calendar extender in the code I posted originally, but I edited it and it is there now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're question has a typo, you are tying to set the sql parameter value to a textbox object, rather than the value of the textbox. You should get the value of it by using `txtEffDate.Text`. Assuming your text box value can only be formatted as a date time (either by a date time picker or setting the type attribute, but the latter doesn't have the same browser compatibility as the former, at this time), then it should cast correctly to a date time in SQL. It can also be converted to a .NET date time by using the function provided by the answer posted previously

Comment: Yes, great answer! I think this solves my problem. It should be: cmd.Parameters.Add("@desiredEffDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = txtEffDate.Text; Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First, I would recommend using a better control, or setting the HTML5 property type in your textbox control:

```
<asp:TextBox ClientIDMode="Static" ID="txtEffDate" runat="server" CssClass="calendarImg" Width="100px" type="date"></asp:TextBox>
```

You can try to convert the date like this:

```
DateTime effDate;    

Try {
    effDate = DateTime.Parse(txtEffDate);
} Catch (FormatException ex) {
    // invalid date string
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am using a calendar extender, but the field is also open for manual entry. I will experiment with adding the type="date". Thank you!